# I'm trying to get stock history using nsepy, but nsepy.get_history() call is returning empty for symbol 'PVR'

Tags: python, nsepy

I'm trying to get stock history using nsepy. get_history() call is returning history for all the symbols except 'PVR', which is empty.

This is the code

```
PVR = get_history(symbol='PVR',
                    start=date(2018,5,1), 
                    end=date(2018,5,10))
print(PVR)
```

gives output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Symbol, Series, Prev Close, Open, High, Low, Last, Close, VWAP, Volume, Turnover, Trades, Deliverable Volume, %Deliverble]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 2):

Use symbol in small-case 'pvr'. 
Try below code:

```
 PVR = get_history(symbol='pvr',
                     start=date(2018,5,1),
                     end=date(2018,5,10))
 print(PVR)
```

This works for me.